# How to link two different forms hook useForm?

Tags: reactjs, form-submit, react-typescript, react-tsx, submit-button

I have a React TypeScript project. There's a parent component that uses a form with the hook `useForm` (the first form), and a second form in a child component (each component is a separate form).

How can you make it, so that when you click the "Submit" button (a button with the type "submit") in the parent component, it also triggers validation of the required fields in the child component?

Additional information: the field validation rules, including their required status, are defined in a schema using Yup.

```
const FizContactUs: React.FC = () => {
  const { getCaseCategories, categories } = useCaseStore()

  const { control, handleSubmit, formState, trigger } = useForm<FizRegFormType>({
    defaultValues: { isConfirmChecked: false },
    resolver: yupResolver(SchemaFizContactUs(categories)),
    mode: 'onChange'
  })

  useForm<FizRegFormType>({
    defaultValues: { phone: '' },
    resolver: yupResolver(SchemaFizReg),
    mode: 'onChange'
  })
  const { currentUser } = useUserStore()
  const { onCaseSubmit, getUserCases } = useCaseStore()
  const { setIsUserLogin } = useProfileStore()

  const [showCodeField, setShowCodeField] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    getCaseCategories()
  }, [])

  const handleSubmitCreateDoc = async (form: FizRegType) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
      setIsUserLogin(true)
      await onCaseSubmit({ ...form })
      if (currentUser?.id) {
        getUserCases(currentUser.id)
      }
    }
  }


  const handleChangeFormField =
    <T,>(triggerName: keyof FizRegFormType, onChangeCallback: (event: T) => void) =>
    (value: T) => {
      trigger(triggerName)
      onChangeCallback(value)
    }

  const handleSetShowCodeField = (value: boolean) => setShowCodeField(value)

  return (
    <>
      <RegFormContactUs showCodeField={showCodeField} onSetShowCodeField={handleSetShowCodeField} />
      <form className="container mt-8" onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSubmitCreateDoc)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="categoryId"
          render={({ field: { onChange, ...field } }) => (
            <ThemeSelect className="mt-8" {...field} onChange={handleChangeFormField('categoryId', onChange)} />
          )}
        />
        {formState.errors?.categoryId && <p className="mt-3 text-red-500">{formState.errors.categoryId.message}</p>}
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="description"
          render={({ field: { value, onChange, ...field } }) => (
            <TextArea
              className="mt-8"
              title="Опишите ситуацию и желаемый результат"
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChangeFormField('description', onChange)}
              {...field}
            />
          )}
        />
        {formState.errors?.description && <p className="mt-3 text-red-500">{formState.errors.description.message}</p>}
        <Controller control={control} name="documents" render={() => <AddDocs />} />
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="isConfirmChecked"
          render={({ field: { onChange, ...field } }) => (
            <UserAgreement
              className="mt-20"
              onChange={handleChangeFormField<boolean | React.ChangeEvent<Element>>('isConfirmChecked', onChange)}
              {...field}
            />
          )}
        />
        {formState.errors?.isConfirmChecked && (
          <p className="mt-3 text-red-500">{formState.errors.isConfirmChecked.message}</p>
        )}
        <Text
          className="bg-myCol-beige w-78 mt-5 px-5 py-3"
          text="Риск неблагоприятного исхода дела из-за неполного описания ситуации несет заявитель."
          variant="Text3"
        />
        <Button className="mt-10" text="Отправить" type="submit" variant="primary" />
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default FizContactUs
```

I tried using the `trigger` function from the hook `useForm` within a function, but it didn't work because it required using this function within the child component.